# Powershell ArgumentList with string

Tags: powershell, start-process

I want to run a powershell process with a command list. I'm having an issue with using a string in an argumentlist with a command list.

This is what I try to run:

```bash
Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList '-command "$var = "test""'
```

But it results in:

```
The term 'test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I tried the same with:

```bash
Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList '-command "$var = `"test`""'
```

But also with a negative result.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: `-ArgumentList '-command', '$var = ''test''; $var; Read-Host'` easier with single-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, PowerShell's *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) requires embedded `"` chars. to be escaped as `\"`, not as `` `" ``:

```bash
Start-Process Powershell -ArgumentList '-command "$var = \"test\""'
```